# Auto-increment arrays for multiple URLs detected in Plain Text

Tags: php

I found a working code online for auto-detecting url's from plain text. The problem I am having is creating an array to display 
multiple URL's if the user inputs multiple URL's into the plain text... I.E When they post a Post or Comment on my website, and 
lets say they have the following text:

```
I found some really good articles on such and such topic. Here are a few links to check out: 
http://www.example.com/hOSDHOUA and https://www.mywebsite.com/h/yIFeelLowIfImHigh and 
http://example-site.com/today-is-a-beautiful-day/.
```

With the code I have now... It will only display the first link and output the 
rest as plain text.  I have searched for the past 7 days on-line but cannot find a working answer to this.

What I am looking for is how to turn the `$url[0]` into an array that automatically increases the output value on the array by 1 
(depending on the amount of links the user has inputted). So in this case it should display as `$url[0]` then next link as `$url[1]` 
and finally the third link as `$url[2]`. But the main key is that I dont want a set (Fixed) number of arrays to be displayed. Instead 
I am looking for an unlimited array output or a max of lets say 200 Limits. I say 200 because the use in which they will be used will 
also be for a SEE ALSO type reference links.

My Code: (PHP)

```
      <?php
        // The Regular Expression filter
        $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
        // The Text you want to filter for urls
        $text = $faq_seealso;  // The variable $faq_seealso refers to my MySQL data fetch query.
                                                         // I will provide it if needed.
        // Check if there is a url in the text
        if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

            // make the urls hyper links
            echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href={$url[0]}>{$url[0]}</a> ", $text); // <--- Part in question

        } else {
            // if no urls in the text just return the text
            echo $text;
        }
      ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what the Output gives me with this code: (Snippet from my website)

```
1. https://www.pokemongosrf.ca https://www.pokemongosrf.ca
1. https://www.pokemongosrf.ca http://kambel.ca
```

As you can see from the Second Line, that the text I had input as 2 separate links are being displayed as 2 links with them both being identical to the first link that was placed in the Textfield. I am looking for them to be displayed as their own unique links and not a clone of the first link. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use `preg_match_all()` to get multiple matches, then replace them in a loop.

Comment: Or use the URL regexp in `preg_replace()`, rather than just the URL that was found in `preg_match()`.

Comment: can you update the question with sample urls your are trying to match ?

Comment: @Barmar Can you show me an example of how to do just that using my code please

Comment: Can't replicate the problem. As I see it it's doing exactly what you want. https://3v4l.org/qr9gn

Comment: @Andreas Your demo replaces all the URLs with the same link to www.example.com. I'm not sure how that's happening.

Comment: @Barmar it's because of $url[0] I believe. I noticed the problem and posted the answer

Comment: Oh, I see, it's using the regexp URL as the search string in `preg_replace()`, I though it was using `$url[0]`, but not using `$0` in the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem now.

Use preg_match_all to match all links and loop them.
In the loop you do a simple str_replace to replace the link with the html anchor.

```
$text ="I found some really good articles on such and such topic. Here are a few links to check out: http://www.example.com/hOSDHOUA and https://www.mywebsite.com/h/yIFeelLowIfImHigh and http://example-site.com/today-is-a-beautiful-day/. ";
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
// The Text you want to filter for urls     

// Check if there is a url in the text
if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
    foreach($url[0] as $link){
        $text = str_replace($link, "<a href={$link}>{$link}</a> ", $text); // <--- Part in question
    }
    echo $text;
} else {
    // if no urls in the text just return the text
    echo $text;
}
//I found some really good articles on such and such topic. Here are a few links to check out: <a href=http://www.example.com/hOSDHOUA>http://www.example.com/hOSDHOUA</a>  and <a href=https://www.mywebsite.com/h/yIFeelLowIfImHigh>https://www.mywebsite.com/h/yIFeelLowIfImHigh</a>  and <a href=http://example-site.com/today-is-a-beautiful-day/.>http://example-site.com/today-is-a-beautiful-day/.</a>
```

https://3v4l.org/W4ifF

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$0` in the replacement string to substitute the corresponding match of the regexp. Using `$url[0]` just returns the first match from `preg_match()`.

```
echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=$0>$0</a> ", $text);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/cdgYJ)

Comment: I think you should add this to your answer: https://3v4l.org/cdgYJ I don't think OP understands the difference in answers